# No Facebook notifications on Yosemite

Tags: macos, notifications, facebook

I run OS X 10.10.2 now, and when I started out with 10.10, I was delighted that Notif Center would send me Notifications when something happened, after I had added the Account in Internet Accounts (I used Lion previously). However, some months ago, it suddenly stopped working, with no clear cause. It was not installing the 10.10.1 update, for instance. Since then, I have been unsuccessful in diagnosing the problem and fixing it. Removing and re-adding the Account did nothing.

Two things I have noticed:

1. When adding the account, no contacts are imported (is this normal?
   Never used it before)
2. I can use notification center to post status updates.

I looked at apple's support forums but most people seemingly have no fix and I find it hard to believe, Apple has done nothing about this (reports start as early as 2012).

Now, the actual question: Can somebody suggest a fix for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a clean install of El Capitan which fixed the problem.